# Pandas data profiling in html

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any reusable code for data profiling in Pandas which gives results in html output.

I've already tried commands from following link but none of the output is in html format.

https://kite.com/blog/python/data-analysis-visualization-python/

Comment: There is a library [pandas-profiling](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/) you can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you simply try [`to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) from the DataFrame you want to export ?

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df.describe().to_html()
```

This outupt html code :

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>a</th>\n      <th>b</th>\n      <th>c</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>count</th>\n      <td>3.0</td>\n      <td>3.0</td>\n      <td>3.0</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>mean</th>\n      <td>4.0</td>\n      <td>5.0</td>\n      <td>6.0</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>std</th>\n      <td>3.0</td>\n      <td>3.0</td>\n      <td>3.0</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>min</th>\n      <td>1.0</td>\n      <td>2.0</td>\n      <td>3.0</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>25%</th>\n      <td>2.5</td>\n      <td>3.5</td>\n      <td>4.5</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>50%</th>\n      <td>4.0</td>\n      <td>5.0</td>\n      <td>6.0</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>75%</th>\n      <td>5.5</td>\n      <td>6.5</td>\n      <td>7.5</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>max</th>\n      <td>7.0</td>\n      <td>8.0</td>\n      <td>9.0</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>
```